# Python library requests return "Error 503" opening a link on heroku

Tags: python, python-3.x, heroku, beautifulsoup, python-requests

This script works fine when I run it locally but when I upload it on Heroku, the *requests.get()* function fail to open the Amazon link returning *<Response 503>* and the script end with the error "*AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'*" (I think this happen because *requests.get()* failed to open the Amazon link). How I can solve the problem so that *requests.get()* return *<Response 200>* on Heroku?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

url = "here is written the Amazon product link"

while True:
    req = requests.get(url, headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0'})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "lxml")
    name = soup.find(id = "productTitle", class_ = "a-size-large product-title-word-break")
    price = soup.find(id = "priceblock_ourprice", class_ = "a-size-medium a-color-price priceBlockBuyingPriceString")
    name = name.get_text()
    price = price.get_text()
    print "New product: ", name, price
    time.sleep(10)
```

**My requirements file:**

```
bs4==0.0.1
requests==2.22.0
lxml==4.5.2
```

**My Procfile file:**

```
web: python "test.py"
```

I tried *requests.get()* with other links and it worked, so I think there is some problem with Amazon.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to write a code that takes google search results as links

```
searchinput = "dogs"
print('Searching...')
    
google_search = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q='+searchinput)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(google_search.text , 'html.parser')

search_results = soup.select('div#main > div > div > div > a')
#for each in search_results:
   #print (each)
   #print("-----------------------")
#print (len(search_results))
linksList = []
......
```

and it was continuing with string operations. I had the same problem from requests. First you can use my code for requests and beatifulSoup. Maybe you can have a problem with request.get() as me and changing the format can help sometimes. Besides, Same problem happened to me after too many requests for same website. Connection blocks you to do it I guess. You can reboost your router. That was working for me.

Please write if your problem is solved with one these methods